# This javascript fails on mouseover

Tags: javascript

can anyone figure out why this JavaScript won't work? It correctly generates the document.write output, but when you try to drag it it starts complaining about top and left not being set. any idea whats wrong?

```
abilitynames=new Array('Heal','Slash','Stab','Poison Slash','Knockout','','','','Tornado','','','','','','','','Icespike','','','','','','','','Bolt','Jumping Bolt','','','','','','','Roast','Burn','','','','','','','Earthquake','Rockwall','','','','','','','Kill','Deflect','Anti-Heal','','','','','','Backslash','Darkwall','Steal','Take','','','','');
abilitytypes=new Array(3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,2,2);
abilitycolors=new Array('#00FF00','#FFFFFF','#0000FF','#FFFF00','#FF0000','#AD6C00','#AD00FF','#000000');
for(i=0;i<64;i++){
document.write("<div onmousedown='dragging=this.id;this.style.position=\"fixed\";this.style.zIndex=1000;this.style.left=event.clientX-75;this.style.top=event.clientY-15;' onmouseout='if(dragging===this.id){this.style.left=event.clientX-75;this.style.top=event.clientY-15;}' onmousemove='if(dragging===this.id){this.style.left=event.clientX-75;this.style.top=event.clientY-15;}' onmouseup='dragging=false;if(event.clientX<450||event.clientY>"+(180+(abilitytypes[i]*90))+"||event.clientY<"+(100+((abilitytypes[i]-1)*(90*abilitytypes[i])/((4%abilitytypes[i])+1)))+"){this.style.position=\"relative\";this.style.top=0;this.style.left=0;this.style.zIndex=0;}else{this.style.left=460;this.style.top=(Math.round((event.clientY-30)/45)*45)+15;if(abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]!=\"\"&&abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]!=this.id){document.getElementById(abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]).style.position=\"relative\";document.getElementById(abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]).style.left=0;document.getElementById(abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]).style.top=0;}abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]=this.id;alert(abilitys);}' id='"+i+"' class='abilityblock"+abilitytypes[i]+"'><div class='abilityicon' style='background-position:"+(Math.floor(i/8)*-20)+"px "+((i%8)*-20)+"px;'></div><div class='abilityname' style='color:"+abilitycolors[Math.floor(i/8)]+";'>"+abilitynames[i]+"</div></div>");
}
```

Comment: Really hard to read when it's all crammed into a one-line string like that...

Comment: Do some work, and format your code to be easier to read, if you want people to help you. Even better - work it into a minimal case. Pasting in your non-working code isn't a good way to ask for help.

Comment: I'm impressed that you've attempted to implement JS drag and drop all on one line.

Answer (score 2):

I've probably broken the script just TRYING to clean up this unholy mess and simplifying things a little, but at least it seems to be a bit more readable now (not including the array definitions):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var dragging;

function mouseDown(el) {
    dragging = el.id;
    el.style.position = "fixed";
    el.style.zIndex = 1000;
    el.style.left = event.clientX - 75;
    el.style.top = event.clientY-15;
}

function mouseOut(el) {
    if (dragging === el.id) {
        el.style.left = event.clientX - 75;
        el.style.top = event.clientY - 15;
    }
}

function mouseMove(el) {
    if (dragging === el.id) { 
        el.style.left = event.clientX - 75;
        el.style.top = event.clientY - 15;
    }
}

function mouseUp(el, i) {
    dragging = false;
    if (    (event.clientX < 450) ||
            (event.clientY > (180 + (abilitytypes[i] * 90)) ) ||
            (event.clientY < (100 + (abilitytypes[i] - 1) * (90 * abilitytypes[i]) / ((4 % abilitytypes[i]) + 1)))) {
        el.style.position = "relative";
        el.style.top = 0;
        el.style.left = 0;
        el.style.zIndex = 0;
    } else {
        el.style.left = 460;
        el.style.top = (Math.round((event.clientY - 30) / 45) * 45) + 15;
        if ((abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY - 120) / 45)] != "") && (abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY - 120) / 45)] != el.id)) {
            var subel = document.getElementById(abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY-120)/45)]);
            subel.style.position="relative";
            subel.style.left=0; 
            subel.style.top=0;
        }
        abilitys[Math.round((event.clientY - 120) / 45)] = el.id;
        alert(abilitys);
    }       
}

    for(var i = 0; i < 64; i++){                                                                                                           
       document.write("               
    <div onmousedown='mouseDown(this);'
        onmouseout='mouseOut(this);'
        onmousemove='mouseMove(el);'
        onmouseup='mouseUp(this, i);'
        id='"+i+"'
        class='abilityblock"+abilitytypes[i]+"'>
        <div class='abilityicon' style='background-position:"+(Math.floor(i/8)*-20)+"px "+((i%8)*-20)+"px;'></div>
        <div class='abilityname' style='color:"+abilitycolors[Math.floor(i/8)]+";'>"+abilitynames[i]+"</div>                           
    </div>");
}
</script>
```

Phew. And after all that, I'm guessing your missing 'left' and 'top' parameters are because your dynamically computed element IDs are generating non-existent IDs in the `mouseup` handler.

My suggestion? Scrap this home-brew drag 'n drop stuff and use the functionality provided by Mootools or jQuery. Far less trouble, especially when having to deal with cross-browser differences.

Comment: +1 for using existing solutions instead of re-inventing the wheel

Comment: +1 - We've implemented our own solid, lightweight drag and drop and it's about 500 lines.  We've had several bugs that deal with different positioning of elements with margins/paddings/fixed height/width, etc. with differences in IE, Firefox etc.  The only reason why we've stuck with it is that we don't already use jQuery.  Otherwise, it would certainly not be worth it, and you're not going to get a solid solution in 1 line of code or the 40 that Marc B has graciously split it up into for you.

Answer (score 1):

Searching your code, you haven't defined an onmouseover event.  You define  onmousedown, onmouseout, onmousemove, and onmouseup.  No onmouseover.